I have a huge problem with abusing my cat, anyone got tips to stop?
I currently have a problem with abusing my kitten/cat, hes currently 1 month old if I'm not mistaken. I found him on the street alone with no mother and sick, I brought him home and took him to the vet etc. Apparently he had an infection in his stomach. He would probably have died if i didnt find him, but that doesnt fix any of my behaviour. I love him alot but I have this problem of abusing him. I hate that part about myself I don't want to hurt him cause I love him but I just snap sometimes and slap him or do some other dumb stuff. I have no idea why I do it. I love cats and I love their company but I still do it for some reason. I read that someone had the same problem and stopped. I rlly hope I can stop this to cause I try to hold myself in but it just doesn't work sometimes. I don't want to hurt him anymore. Anyone got tips so I stop this?
